# Command Line Start TCP SQL Server For Specific Instance

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sqlcmd, wmic

I have researched a line of code that will let me start the TCP/IP service on a SQL Server via the command line. However looking at how it runs I'm thinking it's going to run for ALL the instances on the server. I install SQL on customer servers where they may already have other instances of SQL and I dont really want to start running this when it might alter their configurations. So how can the below be altered to run against a specific instance and not just all of them. I have had a look around and can't seem to find anything. Thanks.

```
WMIC /NAMESPACE:\\root\Microsoft\SQLServer\ComputerManagement12 PATH ServerNetworkProtocol WHERE "ProtocolName='Tcp'" CALL SetEnable
```

Answer (score 0):

Fluked it by trying random snippets from other posts.

```
WMIC /NAMESPACE:\\root\Microsoft\SQLServer\ComputerManagement10 PATH ServerNetworkProtocol WHERE "InstanceName = 'YOURINSTA' and ProtocolName = 'Tcp'" CALL SetEnable
```